# How do I secure my Database credentials in the cypress.config.js file , I am using cypress-sql-server dependency

Tags: sql-server, cypress, automation-testing

I want to secure my credentials of database which is hosted on Microsoft Azure SQL while connecting it with Cypress. I am able to successfully connect and query the database and retrieve values from database when I am providing credentials in the config.js file itself.

**cypress.config.js**

```
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')
const sqlServer = require('cypress-sql-server');

module.exports = defineConfig({
e2e: {
setupNodeEvents(on, config) {



tasks = sqlServer.loadDBPlugin(config.db);
on('task', tasks);

return config
},
},


"db": {
"userName": myusername,
"password": mypassword,
 "server": "myserver",
 "options": {
      "database": "mydb",
      "encrypt": true,
      "rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion": true
   }
  }
  })
```

I want to specify the myusername and mypassword elsewhere and use alias of that because the only loophole I am facing is that I don't want to commit these credentials in master repo (not a secure approach).
I have to commit the file cypress.config.js inside the repo because it contains other config files as well. I am following the documentation of following dependency:

[https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-sql-server?activeTab=readme](https://stackoverflow.com)

My Cypress version:
Cypress package version: 12.8.1
Cypress binary version: 12.8.1
Electron version: 21.0.0
Bundled Node version:
16.16.0

I am new to Cypress and also with DB connectivity with automation, would really appreciate any help from the community.

I tried providing the alias of the connection parameters (username and password) in env section under

```
module.exports = defineConfig({

env: {

userNameDatabase:"DB_USER_int",
passwordDatabase: "DB_PASSWORD_int"

}
```

})

and defining actual values of DB_USER_int and DB_PASSWORD_int in cypress.env.json file , but getting error that Login failed error for user.

Answer (score 4):

Don't put anything secret in `cypress.config.js`. That file needs to be in the public repository, so it's not the place for secrets.

`cypress.env.json` is ok if you have nothing else to depend on in this file, but that's no likely.

Best option is `secrets.json`, put only secret stuff here. Then add to `.gitignore`.

The rest is simple

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')
const sqlServer = require('cypress-sql-server');
const secrets = require('./secrets.json')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      tasks = sqlServer.loadDBPlugin(secrets.db);
```

Comment: Thanks Hogan, it works like charm , Cheers !